# Fitting an exponential curve in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, curve-fitting, exponential

I am trying to fit a curve to this set of data, and nothing I've tried is working.

```
data = {{290, 3.3}, {300, 1.1*10}, {310, 2.9*10}, {320, 7.5*10}, {330, 1.8*10^2}, {340, 4.3*10^2}, {350, 8.3*10^2}, {360, 1.5*10^3}, {370, 3.7*10^3}, {380, 6.3*10^3}, {390, 1.2*10^4}, {400, 2.4*10^4}};
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Qd4.jpg

I've tried
`FindFit[data, Exp[a*x + b], {a, b}, x]`,
`NonlinearModelFit[data, {A*Exp[B*x + D]}, {A, B, D}, x]`,
and many other attempts.

I keep getting the error message

> "Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100
>   iterations"

. I am at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the function being fitted does not model the data well.

```
ClearAll[a, b, c];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a Exp[b Sqrt[x]] + c, {a, b, c}, x, MaxIterations -> 1000]
Show[ListPlot@data, Plot[nlm[x], {x, 290, 400}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

During times like this, it is always useful to take the logarithm of the y-axis values to obtain a better fit. Otherwise, the data points having smaller x-values will be neglected in the fit.

```
ClearAll["`*"];
Clear["Global`*"];
data = {{290, 3.3}, {300, 1.1*10}, {310, 2.9*10}, {320, 7.5*10}, {330, 1.8*10^2}, {340, 4.3*10^2}, {350, 8.3*10^2}, {360, 1.5*10^3}, {370, 3.7*10^3}, {380, 6.3*10^3}, {390, 1.2*10^4}, {400, 2.4*10^4}};
data[[All, 2]] = Log@data[[All, 2]];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*x + b, {a, b}, x, MaxIterations -> Infinity]
Show[ListPlot@data, Plot[nlm[x], {x, 290, 400}]]
```

Plot of data and fit, with the y-axis scaled after taking the logarithm:
[image: Plot of data and fit, with the y-axis scaled after taking the logarithm]